# javascript/html5 charting library for large data-sets

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, zooming, charts

Could you please recommend an interactive charting library that would have ajax scroll/zoom possibility (or at least events tied to x-axis scale) and, optionally, financial analysis features, like [SMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average)/[EMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) trends or polynomial approximation (since performing these tasks on server-side is nothing but a waste of resources).

I have to display a large set of data (statistical info being collected every 5 minutes for couple of years) and wouldn't like to re-invent the wheel, but half day of browsing didn't reveal anything promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zing Chart: http://www.zingchart.com/

Comment: cute, but $1K for 5 domains - its an overkill!

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at http://dygraphs.com - Very powerful do display large sets of data. Further very interesting is also: http://d3js.org/